# HTML stay on the same tab after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need a way to stay on the same tab, this is my HTML code:

```
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Customers', this, 'orange')" <a href="#Customers" data-toggle="pill">Customers</a></button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Online', this, 'orange')" <a href="#Online" data-toggle="pill">Online Sessions</a></button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('History', this, 'orange')" <a href="#History" data-toggle="pill">Historical Sessions</a></button>
<div id="Customers" class="tabcontent">
```

I was trying several ways to do it but non of them work ,
this is one of them:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', jQuery(e.target).attr('href'));
  });
  var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  console.log(activeTab);
  if (activeTab) {
    jQuery('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
  }
});
setTimeout(function() {
  location.reload();
}, 10000);
if (location.hash != '') {
  openPage('Settings', this, 'orange');
}
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Whenever website refresh it goes back to blank (no tab selected) and not staying on the last tab selected.
Also tried `data-toggle="tab"` and same results

Comment: Where is your `openPage` function?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Added

Comment: @KarthickVenkat ? I dont know js or jquary

Comment: Hi @gsr,

Try this once.

var currTab = localStorage.getItem("tab");
$('a[name="' + currTab + '"]').trigger("click");

Comment: Reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/same-tab-after-page-refresh/39684/12

Comment: Just put a tab identifier in the query string. Have a default for when the parameter is not there.

Comment: @KarthickVenkat Added it on <script> above all functions and it didnt do anything..

Comment: @PaulRooney I dont know jquery  so i dont understand what to do, can you write it down for me please?